# How to remove blue frame of link in resume generated by Latex

Tags: latex

I fond that the /href command for link in latex can generate a blue frame around the text. can we remove it?
[blue frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35kp6.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, you can for example use the `colorlink` or the `hidelinks` option. I prefer the colorlinks, because this still gives your readers a chance to see that there is a link.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%hidelinks
colorlinks
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{URL}{text}

\end{document}
```